# ggplot2 and TikzDevice - Removing White Space

Tags: r, ggplot2, tikz

I am using `tikzDevice` package to obtain Latex-friendly graphs in `R`. I am having trouble in removing excessive white spaces from top and bottom of the graph below:
[image: Example]

I have tried using `par(mar)` but it does not seem to work with `ggplot2`. Also, `theme(plot.margins)` seems to unresponsive as well. The white space is introduced as I try to alter the aspect ratio of the figure with `theme(aspect.ratio)`.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

EDIT: Here is a MWE:

```
library(tikzDevice)
library(reshape2)
x = seq(0,1,0.1)
y1 = x^2+2*x+7
y2= x^+2*x+2

df = data.frame(x,y1,y2)
df <- melt(df, id.vars=c("x"))
names(df) <- c("x","$latex~Name$","value")
plot <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=value,color=`$latex~Name$`,group=`$latex~Name$`)) + geom_line() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.4)
plot

tikzDevice(file="mweTex.tex")
plot
dev.off()
```

Comment: How about some code? Not sure what you are actually doing here, the plot looks broken to me.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/36029298/471093

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be caused by some tikz statements that affect the bounding box of the image. Since there doesn't seem to be any option in tikzDevice for minimizing whitespace, I had to think of something else. I managed to fix the generated tikz file by adding the following R code at the end of your MWE:

```
# remove all lines that invisibly mess up the bounding box
lines <- readLines(con="mweTex.tex")
lines <- lines[-which(grepl("\\path\\[clip\\]*", lines,perl=F))]
lines <- lines[-which(grepl("\\path\\[use as bounding box*", lines,perl=F))]
writeLines(lines,con="mweTex.tex")
```

I've tested it on your MWE:

[image: result image]
The left image is without the fix, the right image is with the fix.